# Python3 Cryptodome - how to decrypt pem?

Tags: python, python-3.x, encryption, rsa, pycryptodome

I am trying to decrypt my private key in python using cryptodome. Under raw_cipher_data is my password to encrypt the private key. But I get the error message "ValueError: PEM is encrypted, but no passphrase available"

## MY IMPORT

```
from Cryptodome.Signature import PKCS1_v1_5
from Cryptodome.Hash import SHA
from Cryptodome.PublicKey import RSA
from base64 import b64decode
```

## CODE

```
rsa_key = RSA.importKey(open('pem file location', "rb").read())
verifier = PKCS1_v1_5.new(rsa_key)
raw_cipher_data = b64decode(<your cipher data>)
phn = rsa_key.decrypt(raw_cipher_data)
```

## MY ERROR MSG

```
  File ".\app.py", line 24, in <module>
    rsa_key = RSA.importKey(f.read(), passphrase="CNt3wiSY3Sjn0fEh2fsq")
  File "C:\Users\xx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\Cryptodome\PublicKey\RSA.py", line 733, in import_key
    (der, marker, enc_flag) = PEM.decode(tostr(extern_key), passphrase)
  File "C:\Users\xx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\Cryptodome\IO\PEM.py", line 163, in decode
    data = unpad(objdec.decrypt(data), objdec.block_size)
  File "C:\Users\xx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\Cryptodome\Util\Padding.py", line 90, in unpad
    raise ValueError("Padding is incorrect.")
ValueError: Padding is incorrect.
```

Comment: Please post your error code, post your encryption method. [Minimal, complete and verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) Are you trying to decipher your key or a message?

Comment: @kelalaka I am trying to decrypt my private key.

Comment: @kelalaka sry, I posted it now

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think your RSA key is encrypted. As per the documentation, you should provide the passphrase like this

`rsa_key = RSA.importKey(open('pem file location', "rb").read(), passphrase="yourpasswordhere")`

Comment: Dear @Uku Loskit, yes the file is encrypted. I found the above code in a documentation. Thank you! I will try out with passphrase.

Comment: I get now the error msg: "ValueError: Padding is incorrect."

Comment: it's really important to know for which line this is produced

Comment: a sry @uku loskit : rsa_key = RSA.importKey(f.read(), passphrase="mykey")

Comment: File "C:\Users\xx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\Cryptodome\PublicKey\RSA.py", line 733, in import_key
    (der, marker, enc_flag) = PEM.decode(tostr(extern_key), passphrase)
  File "C:\Users\xx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\Cryptodome\IO\PEM.py", line 163, in decode
    data = unpad(objdec.decrypt(data), objdec.block_size)
  File "C:\Users\rifatbegovic\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\Cryptodome\Util\Padding.py", line 90, in unpad
    raise ValueError("Padding is incorrect.")

Comment: are you sure this is the correct passphrase? how was the key produced?
does this work using the same password:
`openssl rsa -in <pem file location>`?

Comment: Actually yes. I generated the key for my rsa.pem (private key) - with keystore explorer. When I print it out, I get the correct string. "  File "C:\Users\xx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\Cryptodome\PublicKey\RSA.py", line 750, in import_key
    if bord(extern_key[0]) == 0x30:
IndexError: index out of range" | that's what I get after printing the string. He prints my private key and than that.. :S

Answer (score 1):

This helps in decrypting pem.

```
Crypto.IO.PEM.decode(pem_data, passphrase="yourpasswordhere")
```